# Oracle trigger for updating table based on sum of triggering table

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have the following table data structure:

```
PARENT
ID      TOTAL_AMOUNT
101     10
102     15

CHILDREN
ID    PARENT_ID  AMOUNT
201   101        6
202   101        4
203   102        10
204   102        5
```

I'd like to create a trigger that updates PARENT.TOTAL_AMOUNT to be the sum of its child records when CHILDREN is modified. But I can't seem to get around the "table is mutating" restriction.

Using Oracle 11.

EDIT:

Here is code to reproduce the sample scenario above.

```
CREATE TABLE PARENTS (
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  TOTAL_AMOUNT NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE CHILDREN (
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  PARENT_ID NUMBER REFERENCES PARENTS(ID),
  AMOUNT NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO PARENTS( ID, TOTAL_AMOUNT ) VALUES ( 101, 10 );
INSERT INTO PARENTS( ID, TOTAL_AMOUNT ) VALUES ( 102, 15 );

INSERT INTO CHILDREN ( ID, PARENT_ID, AMOUNT ) VALUES ( 201, 101, 6 );
INSERT INTO CHILDREN ( ID, PARENT_ID, AMOUNT ) VALUES ( 202, 101, 4 );
INSERT INTO CHILDREN ( ID, PARENT_ID, AMOUNT ) VALUES ( 203, 102, 10 );
INSERT INTO CHILDREN ( ID, PARENT_ID, AMOUNT ) VALUES ( 204, 102, 5 );


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TEST
  AFTER UPDATE OF AMOUNT ON CHILDREN
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  UPDATE PARENTS
  SET TOTAL_AMOUNT = (
    SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
    FROM CHILDREN
    WHERE PARENT_ID = :NEW.PARENT_ID
  );
END;
/
```

Running the following statement produces error:

```
UPDATE CHILDREN SET AMOUNT = 11 WHERE ID = 204;

Error starting at line : 44 in command -
UPDATE CHILDREN SET AMOUNT = 11 WHERE ID = 204
Error report -
ORA-04091: table RMS.CHILDREN is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "RMS.TRG_TEST", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RMS.TRG_TEST'
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  This is somewhat common as a homework exercise but for real multi-user systems, maintaining aggregate data like this with triggers is generally the wrong approach.

Comment: Not homework. I've simplified my data structure to get at the heart of the problem. We are running into performance issues with various lookups that involve multiple layers of subquerying to get derived data. I've been using views until now but it's becoming noticeably slow, so considering denormalization. Or any other approach.

Comment: A materialized view would generally be a much better solution if that is an option you're open to.

Comment: Bad idea.  Listen to the other comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better to use a `VIEW` or a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` to generate the totals.

If you must use a trigger (don't) then you can change from using `AFTER ... EACH ROW` to an `AFTER` statement trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TEST
  AFTER UPDATE OF AMOUNT ON CHILDREN
BEGIN
  UPDATE PARENTS p
  SET TOTAL_AMOUNT = (
    SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
    FROM   CHILDREN c
    WHERE  c.PARENT_ID = p.ID
  );
END;
/
```

If you want the trigger to be more efficient and only update the `id`s that are modified then you could use a composite trigger.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TEST
  FOR UPDATE OF AMOUNT ON CHILDREN
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  TYPE ids_type IS TABLE OF PARENTS.ID%TYPE;
  ids ids_type := ids_type();
AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF :OLD.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND :OLD.parent_id NOT MEMBER OF ids THEN
      ids.EXTEND;
      ids(ids.COUNT) := :OLD.parent_id;
    END IF;

    IF :NEW.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND :NEW.parent_id NOT MEMBER OF ids THEN
      ids.EXTEND;
      ids(ids.COUNT) := :NEW.parent_id;
    END IF;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;  
AFTER STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN 1 .. ids.COUNT
      UPDATE parents
      SET   total_amount = (SELECT SUM(amount)
                            FROM   children
                            WHERE  parent_id = ids(i))
      WHERE id = ids(i);
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HvBWJr6S)

Comment: Thank you. Views are what I'm using now and finding performance issues. I have tried with materialized view but, unless I'm doing it wrong, they rebuild their entire data set even if only one row is updated, which is hurting the update/insert operation. 

Your compound trigger solution is exactly what I was looking for. So I'll mark this as the answer while taking the point that is not the right approach.

Comment: @Holden You need to create materialized view with `fast` refresh option (which has some prerequisites like MV log on a base table) to allow incremental updates. See [39.4 Determining the Fast Refresh Capabilities of a Materialized View](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/creating-and-managing-read-only-materialized-views.html#GUID-7B26829E-1389-46CF-81AD-28EA6C2F13A1)